# how to convert html object to string react

Tags: reactjs, string, object

i am pretty new to react, and I am trying to print out
"Sending from {sendersname}"

`<Translate value={"sendingFrom"}/>`by itself gives the string: **Sending from**

`consignment.senderName`by itself gives the string: **sendername**

The one line of code i use is:
`<Title heading={<Translate value={"sendingFrom"}/> + consignment.senderName}/>`

The output i get is always:
**[object Object]sendersName**

how can i get `<Translate value={"sendingFrom"}/>` to stay as a string when added with sendername??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Translate>` is a React component instance. An object. You are trying to use concatenation and concatenate an object with a string, which won't work.

Perhaps your solution is:

```
<Title heading={<Translate value={`sendingfrom ${consignment.senderName}`} />} />
```

In my proposal, we will first basically concatenate `sendingFrom` string and `consignment.senderName` and pass that to `Translate` component as a prop. Then, we pass the `Translate` instance to the `Title` component as a prop.

Comment: This works provided that the Translate can actually translate a dynamically generated string. I'm guessing that it looks up a specific key for a given language and returns the translated text for that key.

Comment: I think it'll work because it receives a string and uses replace on it and replaces each word which is found in that string. Really depends how the Translate component is implemented. If it doesn't work, then your answer would be the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it could work if it works like the `Trans` component in `i18next`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Title heading={(
  <React.Fragment>
    <Translate value="sendingFrom" />
    {` ${consignment.senderName}`}
  </React.Fragment>
)} />
```

This will set `heading` to have the value that the Translate component returns, a space, followed by the value of `senderName` next to it.

You could also pass this an array, if you don't like `Fragment`.